# Tell when one and only one key is pressed with logical operators

Tags: logical-operators, mit-scratch

I'm helping someone with a project on Scratch, and it has a block `<if _key_ is pressed>`, and I can tell if a key is pressed, (`a`, `b`, `c`, ...) or when ANY key is pressed.

Using these booleans, `any` and (`a`, `b`, `c` ...), can I tell if one and only one key is pressed *without* checking every single key individually? (e.g. `a` and ONLY `a` is pressed)

Note: I can only use logical operators, not variables or other things.

Comment: the `when [key v] is pressed` block does this... Just select the dropdown

Comment: Sorry, I meant `if [key v] is pressed` and it still doesn't say whether or not other keys are down.

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is if you put `if` `key a pressed` `not` `key a pressed` `and` `key b pressed` `or` `key a pressed` `and` `key c pressed` etc.,  then it could eventually work. The only problem is what if you pressed key `a`, `b`, and `c`, what would happen. I guess though you are pressing `a` and `b` as well as the `c` so it wouldn't work. You know what? The other answer above is better. Ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would be very hard to find a short piece of code to do it without using variables... 
Your best shot if you don't want to do without variables is to make sure if a key is pressed, the other keys are not as shown below...

`When GF clicked`
`if < <key [a] pressed> and <not <key [b] pressed> >`
`do stuff`
`if < <key [b] pressed> and <not <key [a] pressed> >`
`do stuff`

But this is only for keys a and b, so if you want to do it for all 26 alphabetical letters, plus 10 numerals and a space bar, it would be very impractical. I'm not saying it is impossible, it is just very lengthy.

 If you want to use variables, make a variable called `keysPressed` which would be used as a counter of number of keys pressed. You would need to make 38 seperate simple scripts as shown below...

 `When GF clicked`
`forever`

`if <key [a] pressed`

`change keysPressed by (1)`
`wait until <not <key [a] pressed> >`

 `change keysPressed by (-1)`

Then you would need a seperate script after the 38 scripts of mostly copy-paste:

`When GF Clicked`
`Forever`
`if <keysPressed = (1)>`
`do stuff`

I'm not too sure what you want to do, so I just labelled your code after you pressed only 1 key as `do stuff`

Conclusion? Unless you are the impractical dude, use variables!